# Are there any documented sermons by Prophet Muhammad other than the last sermon?

Tags: hadith, history, khutbah

Are there any documented sermons by Prophet Muhammad SAW other than the last sermon?
Preferably full-sermons like khutbah of the Friday prayer or Eid Prayer and not snippets/gist of the khutbah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many sermons collected in different books. You will find some of them in different books of Hadith. And others in the books of Seerah. And there are many books was collecting sermons only.
So, if you read any comprehensive book in Seerah, you will read about many sermons.
And in fact, the last sermon is not one sermon. There are at least 3 sermons.

Comment: jzkk @mostafaizz. any recommended books that collects the sermons only? yes, i have seen snippets of sermons/khutbah in the books of Hadith. i am looking for full khutbah texts.

Comment: If you can read Arabic, there is a list of books in this link
http://www.alukah.net/culture/0/100366/